# RuntimeError: original source dist cannot contain .pyc files

Tags: python, sh

There is a Python file `pip2deb` which contains logic to compile PIP packages specified in config file into Debian packages.

There is a Shell Script which run `pip2deb`.

Config file has multiple entries:

```
Flask==0.12.2
requests==2.18.1
flasgger==0.6.5
```

All of them getting compiled fine except for `flasgger` which gets an error:

```
$ ./build.sh
Collecting flasgger==0.6.5
  Downloading flasgger-0.6.5.tar.gz (1.7MB)
  Saved /tmp/pip2deb_flasgger==0.6.5_9xtW9k/flasgger-0.6.5.tar.gz
Successfully downloaded flasgger
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
running the following command in directory: /tmp/pip2deb_flasgger==0.6.5_9xtW9k/flasgger-0.6.5/tmp_py2dsc/flasgger-0.6.5
/usr/bin/python setup.py --command-packages stdeb.command sdist_dsc --dist-dir=/tmp/pip2deb_flasgger==0.6.5_9xtW9k/flasgger-0.6.5 --use-premade-distfile=/tmp/pip2deb_flasgger==0.6.5_9xtW9k/flasgger-0.6.5.tar.gz bdist_deb
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
running sdist_dsc
running egg_info
writing requirements to flasgger.egg-info/requires.txt
writing flasgger.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to flasgger.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to flasgger.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'flasgger.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'flasgger/ui3/static/css'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'flasgger/ui3/static/fonts'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'flasgger/ui3/static/images'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'flasgger/ui3/static/lang'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'flasgger/ui3/static/lib'
writing manifest file 'flasgger.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 52, in <module>
    'six>=1.10.0'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stdeb/command/sdist_dsc.py", line 123, in run
    raise RuntimeError('original source dist cannot '
RuntimeError: original source dist cannot contain .pyc files
ERROR running: /usr/bin/python setup.py --command-packages stdeb.command sdist_dsc --dist-dir=/tmp/pip2deb_flasgger==0.6.5_9xtW9k/flasgger-0.6.5 --use-premade-distfile=/tmp/pip2deb_flasgger==0.6.5_9xtW9k/flasgger-0.6.5.tar.gz bdist_deb
ERROR in /tmp/pip2deb_flasgger==0.6.5_9xtW9k/flasgger-0.6.5/tmp_py2dsc/flasgger-0.6.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pip2deb.py", line 129, in <module>
    main()
  File "pip2deb.py", line 124, in main
    extra_cfg_file=args.extra_cfg_file,
  File "pip2deb.py", line 84, in download_and_build
    extra_cfg_file=extra_cfg_file,
  File "pip2deb.py", line 66, in build
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['py2dsc-deb', '--dist-dir', '/tmp/pip2deb_flasgger==0.6.5_9xtW9k/flasgger-0.6.5', '/tmp/pip2deb_flasgger==0.6.5_9xtW9k/flasgger-0.6.5.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

The line that causes the error in `pyp2deb` is:

```
subprocess.check_call(cmd, env=env)
```

Any suggestions?

---

**Edit:** I have found out that this problems exists only on Flasgger 0.6.0+ versions. Everything below getting compiled fine. So curious, how the version can affect?

Comment: have you searched for .pyc files and tried to remove them? if it occurs again consider setting `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` env. variable to a value to avoid those to be created, just when you're running the build

Comment: For the sake of experiment I have removed every *.pyc file in the system, yet the problem persists. Is it possible that the script generates conflicting pyc during pip->deb conversion? Can `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` resolve this?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7. Have also tried to run it with the `-B` option - no result.

Comment: Here is the code that raising the error: http://pydoc.net/stdeb/0.8.2/stdeb.command.sdist_dsc/ - search for `contain .pyc files`.

Comment: `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` prevents python from creating .pyc files (unless it is unset by some script) so I'd say it should work